# Information retrieval precision and recall

Tags: machine-learning, classification, information-retrieval

Please help me to solve!! My question is - When a query "q" was fired for an Information Retrieval system having 100 relevant documents w.r.t. the query "q" ,the system in all retrieved 68 documents out of total collection of 600 documents. Out of 68 retrieved documents ,40 documents found to be relevant.

What is the Precision & Recall of the system w.r.t.the given query "q".

Comment: This question is very unclear, please try and structure it better with more information around the system you are using, and the query.

Comment: The question is same as above ! And there is no more description about any query or any thing only mentioned query "q"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can make the following calculations based on the information found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall):

- 68 retrieved documents, with 40 being relevant - hence since precision:  retrieved documents that are relevant/retrieved documents = 40/68 = 58.8%
- you have 100 total relevant documents in the information system - hence the recall: relevant retrieved documents/relevant documents = 40/100 = 40%

Answer (score 0):

**Precision** measures "of all the documents we retrieved as relevant how many are actually relevant?".

```
Precision = No. of relevant documents retrieved / No. of total documents retrieved
```

**Recall** measures "Of all the actual relevant documents how many did we retrieve as relevant?".

```
Recall = No. of relevant documents retrieved / No. of total relevant documents
```

So, in your case, `precision = 40 / 68 = 58.8%` and `recall = 40 / 100 = 40%`